# How to increment a session value in php

Tags: php, authentication, session-variables, increment

I'm working on a login system. I have my login form which posts to check.php.

I'm trying to write a function to test the number of failed login attempts if the user details are incorrect.

```
<?php
//from check.php
if (blah)
{
    $_SESSION['error'] = "<strong>Details not correct.</strong> Please try again.";     
    //$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['attempts'] = 1; //first attempt
    if(isset($_SESSION['attempts']))
    {
        $_SESSION['fail'] = $_SESSION['attempts']++; //increment
    }
    //$_SESSION['fail'] is echo'd on my login form 
}
```

Comment: So What Problem You Are Facing. You Just Described What You Are Doing.

Comment: Doesn't increment...

Comment: You should provide your complete code @user3464091 !

Comment: From where you are calling that function. Please tell. Give that code. And, you are done.

Comment: you have a logic error in your code. you first set your session attenpts to 1, then it will return true, so it will add 1 each times. and set to 1 in the flow time.

Comment: you're seting `$_SESSION['attempts'] = 1` each time, so it'll never be any higher than 2 (after you've incremented it)

Comment: Remember though that any attacker can simply clear their cookies in order to reset the number of attempts made. If you're looking to lock accounts, you would need to record this server side globally and not per session.

Comment: @SilverlightFox That's exactly what I did next once I got the increment working! I used the session to flag the number of failed attempts, then set the user's account to inactive in the database. They can only access their account via a password reset link emailed to them.

Comment: Can't see why you would need session though. If "number of attempts" gets incremented, clearing the cookies will clear it before it is noted in the DB.

Comment: Yeah, I just tested it by deleting my cookies and was able to remove the session and reset the number of attempts. I'll need to amend my script to store the number of attempts in the DB, then write a query to check the number of fails?

Comment: Yes, I'd write each attempt as a row in my table with a bool column for success. Then you can query the number of failed attempts in the last X minutes (say 30). Ps. Don't forget `@` when replying to comments otherwise it doesn't notify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There is **nothing wrong** in this code **except logic**.*

If below code is inside any function. Then, obviously it will stop after incrementing to `2`.  As, `$_SESSION['attempts']` is set to `1` in each and every function call. You have to set `$_SESSION['attempts'] = 1` before that function call.

```
<?php
if (blah)
{
    $_SESSION['error'] = "<strong>Details not correct.</strong> Please try again.";
    if(isset($_SESSION['attempts']))
    {
          $_SESSION['fail'] = $_SESSION['attempts']++; //increment
    }
}
```

> The login form posts to check.php which contains the function, which
>   in turn redirects back to the login form if the error is generated..
>   **~ @user3464091**

If that is the scenario, Then please modify my code to this.

**Explanation** : In this case, after every submit login credential it will come to this function. And, if `$_SESSION['attempts']` is already defined. Then, it will increment to 1. And, if `$_SESSION['attempts']` is not set. Then, it will set it to 1 as initial.

[**NOTE**: Don't forget to `unset($_SESSION['attempts']);` after successful login.]

```
<?php
if (blah)
{
  $_SESSION['error'] = "<strong>Details not correct.</strong> Please try again.";
  if(isset($_SESSION['attempts']))
  {
        $_SESSION['fail'] = $_SESSION['attempts']++; //increment
  } else {
        $_SESSION['attempts'] = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: *Glad.* **I still recommend you to paste your code from where you are calling that function**. And, Please don't forget to mark this answer as correct answer. As, it will help other user to find this answer easily @user3464091

Comment: As I said in my question, the login form **posts** to check.php which contains the function, which in turn redirects back to the login form if the error is generated...

Comment: I have updated my question. Please go through it. You should not get any difficulty @user3464091

Comment: Done. Thanks so much for the detailed answer :)

Answer (score 0):

remove $_SESSION['attempts'] = 1; before your if condition

it should be like this...

```
if(isset($_SESSION['attempts'])) { $_SESSION['fail'] = ++$_SESSION['attempts']; } else { $_SESSION['attempts'] = 1; }
```

Comment: if(isset($_SESSION['attempts']))
        {
            $_SESSION['fail'] = $_SESSION['attempts']++; //increment
        } else {
$_SESSION['attempts'] = 1;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can simply increment it using:

```
$_SESSION['fail']= $_SESSION['attempts']+1;
```

The problem it's stuck on two is that it's defining the session variable first and then executing the program. 
So make sure you don't set the variable unless it hasn't been set.

That is :

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['attempts'])) { $_SESSION['attempts']=1;}
```

Then continue with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing the session value after storing it in a variable. Change

```
$_SESSION['fail'] = $_SESSION['attempts']++;
```

to

```
$_SESSION['fail'] = ++$_SESSION['attempts'];
```

Also, store failed attempts in `$_SESSION['attempts']` otherwise it won't increment beyond 2.

```
$_SESSION['attempts'] = $_SESSION['fail'];
```

Answer (score 0):

use code just like

```
//from check.php
if (blah)
{
    $_SESSION['error'] = "<strong>Details not correct.</strong> Please try again.";     
    //$_SESSION['email'] = $email;

    if(!isset($_SESSION['attempts']))
    {
        $_SESSION['attempts'] = 1; //first attempt
    }
    else
    {
       $_SESSION['attempts']++; //increment
    }
    $_SESSION['fail'] = $_SESSION['attempts'];

//$_SESSION['fail'] is echo'd on my login form 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if (blah)
{
$_SESSION['error'] = "<strong>Details not correct.</strong> Please try again.";     
//$_SESSION['email'] = $email;

if(isset($_SESSION['attempts'])) // check session attempts exist
{
    $_SESSION['fail'] = $_SESSION['attempts']++; //session exist so do increment
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['attempts'] = 1; //  session attempts not exist condition so make first attempt
}


//$_SESSION['fail'] is echo'd on my login form 
}
```

Comment: Please check again